# Motorcycle multi-body model and internal torques

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque

In deriving a model for the in-plane dynamics of a motorcycle and I am facing the problem of reactive torques. The model is a multi-body system, where the bodies of interest are rear wheel, swingarm and main frame.

If we think about a wheel-driven inverted pendulum, we have that the torque applied to the wheel is reacted on the pendulum body.

I am not able to understand how things work with a motorcycle.
The torque applied to the rear wheel comes from the chain forces. I have derived the action of chain forces on swingarm and main body, but I have two issues:

- I do not understand if I have to consider also a reactive torque on the main frame (like the pendulum case) in addition to the chain description.
- In the case I have to, which torque I have to consider as reactive. If it is the torque on the wheel, the one on the secondary output (on the chain smaller sprocket) or the one on the crankshaft.

[image: 1]

Comment: the swingarm is part of the multi body system ? if so you have one more generalized coordinate and you don’t need the reaction forces

Comment: The swingarm is considered as a body in the model, having a rotational degree of freedom, but I do not get the point why no reactive torque is applied on the main frame (the one that includes engine, chassis and rider)

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with the anatomy of a motor cycle, what part in the picture is the "swingarm$?

Comment: It is the one which connects the rear wheel with the chassis of the vehicle, in the picture is the lever surrounded by the chain

Comment: @LucaC Ah, OK thanks.

Comment: "If we think about a wheel-driven inverted pendulum, we have that the torque applied to the wheel is reacted on the pendulum body." Not sure what you mean by a "wheel-driven inverted pendulum".  Also, did you take into consideration the static friction reaction force to the torque applied to the wheel which is responsible for accelerating the motorcycle?